# Grid changes FrameTicksStyle font size

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

I have a contour plot that I'm trying to organize into a grid using `Grid`. But `Grid` changes the `FrameTicksStyle` font size of the fractions. How do I prevent this?

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, π}, {y, -π, π}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-π/2, 0, π/2}, None}, {{}, None}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[14], Directive[14]}]
Grid[{{%, %}, {%, %}}]
```

[image: gridded contour plots]

If you're wondering why I'm using `Grid` instead of `GraphicsGrid`, it's just way easier for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: But only on the fractions, as far as I can tell. Weird.

Comment: Does GraphicsGrid do the same thing? That allows you to set the size of the image, and the font sizes shouldn't change. Don't have access right now to test however.

Comment: `GraphicsGrid` retains the tick marks but adds extra space.

Answer (score 4):

Here is something you might use as a work-around.

```
cp = 
  ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, π}, {y, -π, π}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{{{-π/2, "-π/2"}, 0, {π/2, "π/2"}}, None}, {None, None}}, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[14], Directive[14]}];
Grid[{{cp, cp}, {cp, cp}}]
```

[image: grid]

Comment: Interesting that this trick doesn't work if you try to use "proper" formatting on the fraction. Seems it's really aimed at not having tall tick numbers. This is definitely useful for my purposes, but I'm gonna leave the question open in case someone has a non-work-around answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proper workaround for your problem (which I consider as a nasty bug):

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, π}, {y, -π, π}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{-π/2, 0, π/2}, None}, {{}, None}}, FrameTicksStyle -> 14, 
 BaseStyle -> {ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1}]
Grid[{{%, %}, {%, %}}]
```

[image: screenshot]

Please report this bug to the tech support!

Comment: `BaseStyle -> {ScriptSizeMultipliers -> 1}` could also be used as an option just for `Grid`.

Comment: Super!! Completely unaware of `ScriptSizeMultipliers`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid) automatically changes the script level of its contents. This is what you're seeing. All you need to do is to add the option `AllowScriptLevelChange->False` to your [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid):

```
ContourPlot[
    x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, π}, {y, -π, π},
    FrameTicks -> {{{-π/2, 0, π/2}, None}, {{}, None}},
    FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[14], Directive[14]}
]
Grid[
    {{%, %}, {%, %}},
    AllowScriptLevelChange->False
]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an extendion of m_goldberg's answer.

Create the following fraction (Esc pi Esc ctrl-/2)

[image]

in your notebook and paste it into the text for the tick label. Then wrap the text in `Style` and make it size 18. When it shrinks in the grid you will approximately the same size for all of the tick labels.

```
cp = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, π}, {y, -π, π}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{{-π/2, 
        Style["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(-π\), \(2\)]\)", 18]}, 
       0, {π/2, 
        Style["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(π\), \(2\)]\)", 18]}}, 
      None}, {None, None}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[14], Directive[14]}];
```

and then

```
Grid[{{cp, cp}, {cp, cp}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a fair amount of work. If you are doing this a great deal you will probably need to automate it.

Comment: You're gonna like this: `ToString[-π/2, StandardForm] // InputForm`

Comment: @JackLaVigne Your "solution" creates the opposite problem for `cp` (without `Grid`). Also it would be much simpler to write `FrameTicks -> {{{{-\[Pi]/2, Style[-\[Pi]/2, 18]}, 0, {\[Pi]/2, Style[\[Pi]/2, 18]}}, 
   None}, {None, None}}` what produces the same result.